# dustjs: how to profile and/or time rendering?

Tags: node.js, express, profiling, dust.js, kraken.js

I'm debugging some dustjs template render sluggishness after calling res.render from an express controller. There are a few (fast) async calls from dust helpers, but even when they're removed I'm occasionally seeing templates take multiple seconds to render, which is surprising since they're all pre-compiled.

Is there any built in timing/logging for dustjs or do I just need to profile the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some simple profiling in Node by monkey-patching `dust.render` like this:

```
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
var render = dust.render;
dust.render = function(name, context, callback) {
  var timeStart = process.hrtime();
  render(name, context, function() {
    var timeDiff = process.hrtime(timeStart);
    console.log(name, timeDiff[0] * 1000 + timeDiff[1] / 1000000);
    callback.apply(undefined, arguments);
  });
};
```

When you run your application, look at the console to see how much time rendering takes. Rendering a normal Dust template takes on the order of milliseconds.

```
> node app.js

hello 0.832608
Hello world! Using Dust version 2.7.1!
```

This template took 0.8ms to render.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great for debugging single requests. For full page rendering of pre-compiled templates (w/o any async requests) I'm seeing between 300 and 600 ms, sometimes hanging to 1500ms. In your experience with dust have you noticed any methods or patterns that are significant bottlenecks?

I have templates with a lot of nesting and iteration, some of which make liberal use of custom dust helpers that perform heavy logic and some iteration themselves, as well as lots of context.get(). Do you have any best practices for helpers? (ie passing params instead of context.get, etc).

Comment: Compiled dust templates basically pass functions around. There's very little overhead. In helpers, you can use `chunk.write` to write directly to the current chunk instead of `chunk.render` if you don't need Dust to handle the rendering... that would help. Other than that I would start profiling individual helpers in a similar fashion as above.